# How to return slack users and their status?

Tags: python, python-3.x, slack-api

I am using two slack API's, users.list() and users.getPresence(). I use users.list() to retrieve the user's names and IDs.

The users.getPresence() API takes the user ID as a parameter and only outputs their presence of 'active' or 'away' as it is shown here: https://api.slack.com/methods/users.getPresence

I tried taking the names I retrieved from users_list() and returning them along with the users_getPresence() API, but then I only got the list of names to repeat over each status.

```
client = slack.WebClient(API_KEY)
def users_list():
    users_call = client.users_list()
    users = users_call['members']
    result = []
    # loops for each user
    for user in users:
        uid = user['id'] 
        name = user['profile']['real_name']
        info = {"id": None, "name": None}
        if users_call['ok']:  
            info['id'] = uid
            info['name'] = name
            result.append(info) 
        else:
            return None
    return result

def users_getPresence():
    info = users_list()
    users = []
    for value in info:
        uid = value['id']
        users.append(uid)
    presence = []
    for user in users:
        presence_call = client.users_getPresence(user = user)
        if presence_call['ok']:
            presence.append(presence_call['presence'])
        else:
            return None
    return presence
```

Right now, the two API's have separate outputs, where users.list() returns ID and name while users.getPresence() returns presence.

How can I return the user's name and their status together?

Comment: Just create a dictionary from your users list with the user ID as key. Then add the presence information per user to that dictionary.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken As you suggested, I created a dictionary, but I didn't use the id as a key, I used the name as a key and looped through it, so I have each user's name shown, but their status doesn't follow through. What's happening is each user's name is shown, but the status is the status of the first user in the list. Do you know how I can properly link the status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an updated version of your 2nd function that returns the list of all users with their presence status. Notice that I also added a sleep so you do not violate the rate limit of max 50 calls per minute.

```
def users_getPresence():            
    users = users_list()
    for user in users:
        presence_call = client.users_getPresence(user = user['id'])
        sleep(1.2)
        if presence_call['ok']:
            user['presence'] = presence_call['presence']
        else:
            user['presence'] = None
    return users
```

I also saw a couple of issues with your first function. Mainly checking for ok in the loop does not work, because if the method fails it will not contain any users and your script will fail before it reached the ok check.